# Issue with creating head of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

My code is designed to read a series of strings from a hashed linked list, convert them all to lowercase, put them into an array to use quicksort on them, and then put them into a data structure called word count that includes the word and how many times it appears in the documents. Currently when I run the code, it prints out correctly with the print statements I am using, but the head is always set to null when I print it out.

Here is the wordCount declaration:

```
typedef struct wordCount
{
    int count;
    char *word;
    struct wordCount* next;
} wordCount;
```

Here is the method segment that is supposed to do what I described above.

```
else
    {
        char *toSort[curSize];
        int linkedListTraverse = 0; //Array index for each linked list node
        while(linkedList != NULL)
        {
            toSort[linkedListTraverse] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(linkedList->string));
            strcpy(toSort[linkedListTraverse],linkedList->string); //Copy the data from the linked list into an array 
            linkedList = linkedList->next;
            linkedListTraverse++;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while(i < curSize) //Convert all of the words to lowercase
        {
            char* str = toSort[i];
            char *p;
            for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++)
                *p = (char)tolower(*p);
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        qsort(toSort, curSize, sizeof(char*), stringCmpFunc); //Sort the current node
        while(i < curSize)
        {
            printf("%s\n", toSort[i]);
            i++;
        }
        int curWordIndex = 0;
        int checkWordIndex = 1;
        wordCount *wordHead = NULL;
        wordCount *curWord = wordHead;
        while(curWordIndex < curSize)
        {
            curWord = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
            curWord->word = toSort[curWordIndex]; //Set the word
            curWord->count = 1; //Start the count out at 1
            while(strcmp(toSort[curWordIndex], toSort[checkWordIndex]) == 0) //While the two words are equal
            {
                checkWordIndex++; //Advance the leading index check
                curWord->count++;
                if(checkWordIndex >= curSize) //If the leading index goes beyond the array bounds
                    break;
            }
            if(checkWordIndex < curSize)
            {
                curWordIndex = checkWordIndex;
                checkWordIndex = curWordIndex + 1;
            }
            if(checkWordIndex >= curSize) //If the leading index goes beyond the array bounds
            {
                    if(strcmp(curWord->word, toSort[curWordIndex]) != 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s %d\n", curWord->word, curWord->count);
                        curWord = curWord->next;
                        curWord = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
                        curWord->word = toSort[curWordIndex]; //Set the word
                        curWord->count = 1; //Start the count out at 1
                    }
                    break;
            }
            //printf("CurWordIndex: %d\n CheckWordIndex: %d\n",curWordIndex, checkWordIndex);
            printf("%s %d\n", curWord->word, curWord->count);
            curWord = curWord->next; //Advance to the next node in the linked list
        }
        printf("%s %d\n", curWord->word, curWord->count);
```

And here is the code segment that only prints null

```
curWord = wordHead;
        while(curWord != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s %d\n", curWord->word, curWord->count);
            curWord = curWord->next;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
if (wordHead == NULL) { wordHead = curWord; }
```

after

```
curWord = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
```

*Updated*

Here is another problem:

```
curWord = curWord->next;
curWord = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
```

It should be:

```
curWord->next = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
curWord = curWord->next;
```

*Note*:
Please, follow the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help us to help you.

*Updated/2*

Replace this:

```
while(curWordIndex < curSize) {
    curWord = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
```

with this:

```
while(curWordIndex < curSize) {
    wordCount* tmp = (wordCount*) malloc(sizeof(wordCount));
    if (curWord) { curWord->next = tmp; }
    curWord =  tmp;
```

Comment: That makes it so the head is set up correctly, but I still think the rest of the linked list isn't getting set up correctly. Whenever the loop to print the linked list starting from the head runs, only the head of the linked list is printed.

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your help. Even with the two changes you suggested, the loop that uses the head to print out the linked list is still only printing the head of the linked list and then exiting. Also, which part of the rules was I neglecting to follow? I want to make sure I don't break the rules.

Comment: @ColinNull, it's not complete, at least.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being difficult with needing this much help help, but the loop change you added didn't fix the issue, it is still only creating the head of the linked list and not joining things together correctly.